# NSArray - Cant get value out of array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I have an mutable array that I make in viewDidLoad like this:

```
self.dayOrder=[NSMutableArray new];

NSCalendar *cal=[NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSInteger dayNumber = [cal component:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:[NSDate date]]-1; // Sunday gives 0,

for (int i=0;i<7;i++) {
    [self.dayOrder addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:dayNumber]];
    dayNumber=(dayNumber+1)%6;
}
```

Then in cellForRowAtInxdexPath, I want to get a value out of this array but when I call this

```
NSNumber *dayNumber=self.dayOrder[indexPath.row];
```

and then I log dayNumber it logs a list of the number 99. But when I log just the array it looks fine?

Thanks for the help in advance.

I log day number like this

```
NSLog(@"%d", dayNumber);
```

HERE is cell for row method

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

//    NSNumber *dayNumber=self.dayOrder[indexPath.row];
    NSNumber *dayNumber= [self.dayOrder objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSInteger buttonNumber = [self.mealdata mealsForDay:indexPath.row].count;

//    NSLog(@"%d", dayNumber);

      NSLog(@"%d", self.dayOrder);
```

This is what gets logged in cellForRow method `NSLog(@"%d", dayNumber);`

```
2014-10-25 15:56:24.683 U Eat[79938:2166115] 99
2014-10-25 15:56:24.687 U Eat[79938:2166115] 99
2014-10-25 15:56:24.689 U Eat[79938:2166115] 99
2014-10-25 15:56:24.690 U Eat[79938:2166115] 99
2014-10-25 15:56:24.691 U Eat[79938:2166115] 99
2014-10-25 15:56:24.692 U Eat[79938:2166115] 99
2014-10-25 15:56:24.693 U Eat[79938:2166115] 99
2014-10-25 15:56:24.829 U Eat[79938:2166115] 99
2014-10-25 15:56:24.835 U Eat[79938:2166115] 99
2014-10-25 15:56:24.838 U Eat[79938:2166115] 99
2014-10-25 15:56:24.840 U Eat[79938:2166115] 99
```

[image]

Comment: Please show how you log `dayNumber`.

Comment: @Roma-MT's suggestion shouldn't make a difference, but dasblinkenlight's on the right track.

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by this sentence: "...and then I log dayNumber it logs a list of the number 99. But when I log just the array it looks fine". Log it where? In your cellForRowAtIndexPath method? What do yo mean "a list of the number 99?" How can a single NSNumber have contain a list? And what is "a list of the number 99"? Where do you log the array? In viewDidLoad?

Comment: You need to post your entire viewDidLoad method, your entire CellForRowAtIndexPath method, and the declaration of your dayOrder array property. I would suggest logging the array contents both in viewDidLoad and in CellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @DuncanC i have logged it in view did load I will add the logs to question

Comment: No need to do what @DuncanC's suggested. dasblinkenlight's answer is right... NSLog(@"%d", dayNumber); should be NSLog(@"%@", dayNumber);

Comment: @LyndseyScott, Righto. His original post did not include the log statement.

Comment: You're logging the address of an NSNumber.  (And likely just the high-order part.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the way that you log `dayNumber`: since it is an `NSObject`, you should log it like this:

```
NSLog(@"Row=%d, Day=%@", indexPath.row, dayNumber);
```

Note that the row is logged like an integer with `%d`, while `dayNumber` is logged like an object with `%@`.

Comment: Ah-ha. When he updated his post with the log statement, all became clear. (voted)

Comment: okay that works but I still can't get the value out of this array to be used, as an NSInteger

Comment: I'm using this `[dayNumber integerValue]` but it doesn't wokr

Comment: @LyndseyScott okay great

Comment: @iqueqiorio Actually when you say "that works" what result are you getting?

Comment: @LyndseyScott i get this `2014-10-25 16:31:48.354 U Eat[80718:2190716] Row=0, Day=6
2014-10-25 16:31:48.356 U Eat[80718:2190716] Row=1, Day=1
2014-10-25 16:31:48.356 U Eat[80718:2190716] Row=2, Day=2
2014-10-25 16:31:48.357 U Eat[80718:2190716] Row=3, Day=3
2014-10-25 16:31:48.357 U Eat[80718:2190716] Row=4, Day=4
2014-10-25 16:31:48.358 U Eat[80718:2190716] Row=5, Day=5
2014-10-25 16:31:48.358 U Eat[80718:2190716] Row=6, Day=0
2014-10-25 16:31:48.513 U Eat[80718:2190716] Row=0, Day=6`  But i still can't use the vouch?

Comment: Then [dayNumber integerValue] should work... How are you determining that it doesn't work? Are you using another NSLog? And if so, what code are you using in that NSLog?

Comment: @iqueqiorio Lyndsey Scott is right, `[dayNumber integerValue]` should definitely work. Assign the result to an `int` variable, and use it like an integer.